# How to check, is excel plugin enabled in PERL

Tags: perl

Am just started working for exporting excel spread sheet in PERL,

Before start i want confirmation, that is, is excel spread sheet realted plug is enabled or not,

Advise some simple PERL  syntax ,

Thanks

Comment: PERL is not an acronym - you mean Perl :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a module from CPAN such as [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://p3rl.org/Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX) then you can just use a simple script to test if the module is installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
```

And run that script. You'll get an error about

```
Can't locate Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm in @INC
```

if the module is not installed on your system.

Comment: If that's what you want, then you don't even need a script. Just typing "perl -MExcel::Writer::XLSX" on the command line will give you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If by "excel plugin" you mean a CPAN module, then the solution is to try to load it and see what happens. If you wrap the loading attempt in an "eval" statement then your program won't die if it fails.

Something like this:

```
eval 'use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel';

my $have_module = ! $@;
```

This method is a little imprecise as I'm just looking to see if $@ has been given a value. For more control, you might want to check the contents of $@ for specific error message. You're looking for one that starts "Can't locate ...".

Comment: when only checking for success, I like to use eval's return value directly: `my $have_module = eval {require Spreadsheet::ParseExcel};` then you don't have to bother with `$@` or any of its edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean:

> How can I tell if an Excel document delivered from my webserver to a browser will open in a browser plugin (as opposed to being saved or opened in a standalone application)?

Then you can't. Browsers don't send that information to the server, so no server side process (written in Perl or otherwise) can tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MExcel::Writer::XLSX -e "print 'ok'"
```

If it prints 'ok' then you're good. If you get a `can't locate ... in @INC` then you need to install it.